# Retrieve inner field Map<Object, String> from Mybatis

Tags: sql, spring-boot, dictionary, mybatis

I have class `Cart` and `Item`

```
@Data
public class Cart {

    private Long id;
    private Map<Item, Long> items;

    public Cart() {
        items = new HashMap<>();
    }
}

@Data
public class Item {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private ItemType type;
    private Boolean available;

}
```

And I would like to get this object with HashMap inside from database with Mybatis in xml.
I have next query with such data:

```
SELECT c.id          as cart_id,
           i.id          as item_id,
           i.name        as item_name,
           i.description as item_description,
           i.price       as item_price,
           i.type        as item_type,
           i.available   as item_available,
           ci.quantity   as item_quantity
    FROM carts c
             JOIN carts_items ci ON c.id = ci.cart_id
             LEFT JOIN items i on i.id = ci.item_id
    WHERE c.id = #{id}
```

So I haven't found any solution for this problem and I hope you can help with code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change a bit my structure
I added `private List<CartItem> cartItems;` where I store all items fields and quantity.
And also I override `getItems()` method:

```
    public Map<Item, Long> getItems() {
        return cartItems.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(CartItem::getItem, CartItem::getQuantity));
    }
```

So now I set data into list of `CartItem` objects and map them into Map when it is needed